# How exactly does Postfix notation work?

Tags: replacement, syntax, input-forms, precedence

I guess I've been using the [`Postfix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html) notation `//` wrongly for some time now. I assumed it was a quick way to apply a function to all that precedes it. Now I was surprised by the fact that for example

```
a // f /. a -> 1
```

outputs

> ```
> f[a]
> ```

I would have expected this to either be the same as `(a // f) /. a ->1`, or as applying the replacement rule first  and then the function `(a /. a -> 1) // f`. However, both would output `f[1]`.

Examining `a // f` with `FullForm` (and `Hold`) does not give me any insight to what is happening either.

The `Postfix` documentation is unfortunately very limited. This seems rather trivial, so sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any post about this.

Comment: Try evaluating this: `FullForm[Hold[a // f /. a -> 1]]`, it should help (in general) understanding the order of operations Mathematica invokes.

Comment: The wily programmer uses parentheses to exactly guarantee order of operations. I use "//" lots, and have been bitten by it before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would have expected this to either be the same as `(a // f) /.a ->1`, or as applying the replacement rule first and then the function `(a /.a->1)//f`

It is neither of those. It is a precedence issue.  It is interpreted as

```
a // (f /. a -> 1)
```

[You can look it up](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html), or you can check it like this:

```
PrecedenceForm@HoldForm[a // f /. a -> 1]

(* (f /. a -> 1)[a] *)
```

---

Comment from @andre:

> To see precedences you can also select `a` then extend the selection (with multi-click on `a` or with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> on Windows (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> on Mac). Then observe the size of the blocks by wich the selection extends. Very useful, I use it all the time.

Comment: To see precedences you can also select `a` then extend the selection (with multi-click on `a` or with Ctrl-Shit-. on windows. Then observe the size of the blocks by wich the selection extends. Very usefull, I use it alt the time.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you. I don't know why I didn't consider that possibility for precedence. Thanks also especially for including `PrecedenceForm@HoldForm'.